# A named connection string was used, but the name 'tumoDB' was not found in the application's configuration. .Net core 3.0 REST API

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

Hi Could you please assist,i have run a scafold from my database using the below PM command and it works fine and the DB context is created.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=tumoDB;User ID=tumo;password=****" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Infrastructure\Models -Tables BnplIndicator -f
```

But when i try to follow .Net security principles by placing th the connectionstring in appsettings.json,i get the error in the title that the name of my DB(tumoDB) is not found,please see my connection strings bellow.

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySql": {
      "PhoneAppDB": {
        "ConnString": "Server=(localhost)\Sql1;uid=tumo;pwd=****;Convert Zero Datetime=True;",
        // "ConnString": "Server=(localhost)\Sql2;port=3030;Database=MohemStores;user=root;password=***;",
        "Timeout": 60000,
        "MaxRetries": 6
      }
    },
    "SqlServer": {
      "tumoDB": {
        "ConnString": "Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=tumoDB;User ID=tumo;Password=***;",
        "Timeout": 60000,
        "MaxRetries": 5
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

and now i use this below i get the error:tumoDB was not found in application configuration

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection Name=tumoDB Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Infrastructure\Models -Tables BnplIndicator -force
```

I researched and even added the code in the Iconfiguration in Startup.cs as recommended but still getting the same error,please note all required packages (EF.Sqlserver and EF.tools) are installed properly and the API runs it is just the command to scafold DBcontext using the name that gives problems.

```
   services.AddCustomDataStoreConfiguration(Configuration);
            services.AddDbContext<tumoDBContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("tumoDB")));
```

Comment: That settings file doesn't look like the example in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Comment: The Data Source value is never localhost. It is the name of your PC followed by SQL Server Instance (in case if you are using SQLEXPRESS). Hence the DataSource value would be DataSource= YourPCName\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Also Try Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnString") instead of tumoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found what the answer was,you cannot create a sub connection string under another connection string.

Solution:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   
      "PhoneAppDB":"Server=(localhost)\Sql1;uid=tumo;pwd=****;Convert Zero Datetime=True;",   
  
      "tumoDB": 
        "ConnString": "Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=tumoDB;User ID=tumo;Password=***;"
       
  },
```